# Inverting mouse direction

Tags: osx, mouse

Where can I find the "invert mouse direction" setting that used to exist? With 2.92 the direction of scroll is reversed from previous settings and there doesn't appear to be a way to fix it.

Using Mac, blender 2.92

Thanks in advance, must just be missing the menu item

Answer (score 1):

Edit>Preferences>Navigation>Zoom>Invert zoom direction.

Make sure that your 'zoom method' is 'dolly' or 'continue'.

Hope that helps!

Upvote and mark as accepted if it does.

Comment: That was where the setting used to be, as I said, in 2.92, it is no longer there.

Comment: I can see it there. I am using 2.92.0

Comment: Oh! I just found the answer. Make sure the zoom method is 'dolly' or 'continue'. When the zoom method is 'scale' that option isn't there.

Comment: The 3D viewport is still inverted with those changes applied, the navigation is still inverted from 2.91.

Comment: Is the checkbox checked?

Comment: Yes, the checkbox was indeed checked.

Comment: Okay. Try unchecking it on dolly mode. That worked for me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124936/discussion-between-rowan-mcalpin-and-user85015).